# open url in separate process

Tags: java, linux, browser, runtime, detach

I'm using the following code to open a specific url in linux default browser.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("xdg-open " + url + ");
```

The above code works fine when executed using a shell script, but the browser closes when ever I close the terminal. After doing some research on google, I found the following code segment.

```
rt.exec("sensible-browser " + url + " </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown");
```

Which will open the default browser and disown the process. But Still the browser is bound to the terminal which I started. How can I detach the process from the terminal?

Comment: Try adding `setsid` at the beginning of the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rt.exec("nohup sensible-browser \"" + url + "\" >>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null &");` to "unbind" the Browser by using a hidden console